# How do I set who can use my Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

I had a single Chromecast in my network. So to lock it down to myself and not allow others on my network to cast to mine, I simply created two networks; one is isolated and one has isolation off. I simply connect to "my" SSID of the network.

Now we have two Chromecasts. So to allow for this new guest cast to function publicly, I had to turn wireless isolation off in the public SSID.

**Problem**

People can now see and cast my private Chromecast I have on a my private SSID, including the Chromecast in the public SSID. So we all see two Chromecasts.

**Solution**

I need people in the public SSID of my 1 single router to see only their public cast.
I don't care whether the private SSID sees the public cast or not. I just need to see my private cast.

**Available Equipment**

- 1 single router serving 3 SSIDs (can serve up to 4) with separate wireless isolation option for each SSID.
- 2 Chromecast; one is public, one is private.

**Tried**

Wireless isolation: Works when there's one cast.

Firewall rules:

- Local machine firewall: Works to block viewing my cast from public Windows machines. But public iPhones and Androids can still see my private cast.
- Router firewall: only allows for port controls. Can't block access to specific LAN IP. However I tried blocking using block list of "domain names or keywords" but that didn't work.

**Extra**

My private cast has a fixed LAN IP. Just as all my private devices.
Two SSIDs have different names and different WPA2 passwords. (That didn't thwart public people from viewing my private cast though).

Comment: You can try enabling **Guest Mode** on your public Chromecast, while keeping Isolation on. Or is there a way, on your router, to isolate between the SSIDs rather than within the SSIDs?

Comment: Couldn't isolate SSIDs. And I can't use location proximity option as"public" in this question means about 5 extra people who keep throwing casts on the wrong device. Turning location, however, will make that no less than 20 people. Others whom I don't know or trust.